# I have troubles replacing a word in text file

Tags: python

My code works but the problem is that replaces at the wrong places.

Could somepone take a look and better my code.

```
def find():

    openfile = open(filename, "rt")

    closefile = open(filename, "wt")


    inp1 = input(search)
    inp2 = input(replace)
    for line in fileopen:
        newword = fileout.write(line.replace(inp1, inp2))

    openfile.close()
    closefile.close()
    return newword

find()
```

Comment: simple way -  add spaces around, good way - use regex

Comment: The issue is that `explain` **does** contain the substring `in`. If you only want to replace a substring if it makes a separate word you do *not* want to use the `str.replace` method but instead use a regex and the `re.sub` function

Comment: @GiacomoAlzetta could you possibly show me how to use it, I am very new to python

Comment: @splash58 could you possibly show me how, in my code I am very knew to python

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @splash58 said, the simple way is to add spaces around the word:

```
newword = line.replace(' ' + searchinput + ' ',' ' + replaceword + ' ')
```

And the better way is to use regex, meaning add the word boundaries (`\b`) when searching

```
import re
newword = re.sub(r'\b{}\b'.format(searchinput),replaceword,line)
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use a [regex](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html) for this! A regex allows you to search for word boundaries as well as specific substrings. You can use the `\b` identifier for this. This way you know for sure that you pick up only the complete word, and not when it's part of another word.

```
import re

filterword = input('The word to replace:')
regex = "\\b" +filterword+"\\b"
replacement = input("The word to replace with:")
myString = "I tried to explain in the train."

print(f"Replacing in:\n {myString}")
print(re.sub(regex, replacement, myString))
```